# Parse Adding objects not working

Tags: swift, heroku, parse-platform

Parse Server on Heroku (the open sourced version of course).

This is my iOS code in swift. I must say that the Parse SDK is running fine. I can query other tables and do a lot of stuff so I know that that part is all okay.
I have been querying existing data only until now, but today I tried adding stuff to table for the first time, and I'm having a hard time with it.

The following is my code:

```
let step_object = PFObject(className: "driver_steps")
step_object.add("Was directed to drive to first location", forKey: "step_string")
step_object.saveInBackground()
```

The object printed to the console looks fine to me:

```
print("the object is \(step_object)")
```

outputs:

```
the object is <driver_steps: 0x1844b54e0, objectId: new, localId: (null)> {
ACL = "<PFACL: 0x18043f720>";
"step_string" =     (
    "Was directed to drive to first location"
);
}
```

Nothing is being saved for me in the database though. I wonder where I went wrong with this?

Comment: Use `saveInBackground { (success, error) in ... }` instead and print success and error inside it

Comment: Thanks @nathan. So that gave me the following error so I figured out that my initial code "step_object.add"  was wrong . Indeed the correct way to input a new object is different and I post that in my answer. 
The error I got back was:

    expected String but got Array" UserInfo={code=111, temporary=0, error=schema mismatch for driver_steps.step_string; expected String but got Array, NSLocalizedDescription=schema mismatch for

Comment: Use subscripting (`step_object["step_string"] = "Was directed to drive to first location"`) to set an object's attributes or better yet, subclassing.

Comment: That's correct. I just posted that as my answer. Thanks again and all the best!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to add a complete new object using Parse SDK is different than in my question. It should be as so:

```
let step_object = PFObject(className: "driver_steps")
step_object["step_string"] = "Was directed to drive to first location"
step_object.saveInBackground()
```